# Error 500 internal al querer importar documento php usando jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
        <?php

    require ("scripts/scriptValidaSession.php");
    require ("clases/usuario.class.php");
    require ("clases/ticket.class.php");
    require ("clases/baseDatos.class.php");

    if(isset($_GET['archivo'])){

      !$_GET['archivo'] ? $error = "¡El formato del archivo no esta Permitido!" : $error = "El archivo es muy grande!.";
    }
    else
      $error = "Solo se admiten imagenes hasta un maximo de 2mb.";

    $conexion = new baseDatos();

    if ($conexion->connect_errno) {

        echo "Fallo la conexion: ".$conexion->connect_error;
    }

    $usuario = new Usuario();

    $consulta = $usuario->searchUser($conexion, $_SESSION['ticket_id']);

    $resultado  = $consulta->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $ticket = new Ticket();

    $consulta_pendientes = $ticket->numSlope($conexion, $_SESSION['ticket_id']);

    $resultado_pendientes = $consulta_pendientes->num_rows;

    ?>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

setInterval(function(){
    $('#parte2').load('datos.php')
}, 3000);

});
</script>

<body>
<div class="parte" id="parte2">
</body>
</html>
```

este es mi archivo index , ahora mi archivo datos.php , que esta ubicado en la misca carpeta que el archivo index.php

```
     <div class="card-panel white lighten-4">
<h4 class="header blue-text">lista de solicitudes</h4>
      <table class="highlight responsive-table ">

        <thead>
          <tr>

            <th>Ticket</th>        
            <th>Servicio</th>
            <th>Monto</th>
            <th>N&#258;Âºmero</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Hora</th>          
            <td></td>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php
            $conexion = new baseDatos();

            if ($conexion->connect_errno) {

                echo "Fallo la conexion: ".$conexion->connect_error;
            }

            $ticket = new Ticket();

            if($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 3){

              $consulta = $ticket->listTicketUnrevisedEmpleado($conexion, $_SESSION['ticket_id']);
            }
            elseif($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 2){

              $consulta = $ticket->listTicketUnrevisedSupervisor($conexion, $_SESSION['ticket_id_departamento']);
            }
            elseif($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 4){

              $consulta = $ticket->listTicketUnrevisedGerente($conexion, $_SESSION['ticket_id_cede']);
            }
            elseif($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 1 || $_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 5){

              $consulta = $ticket->listTicketUnrevised($conexion);
            }

            $consultaRefresh = $ticket->listTicketRefresh($conexion);

            $registros = $consultaRefresh->num_rows;

            while ($resultado   = $consulta->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

              $usuario = new Usuario();

              $consulta_usuario = $usuario->searchUser($conexion, $resultado['id_usuario']);

              $resultado_usuario  = $consulta_usuario->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

              if($resultado['tipo_solicitud']==1)
                $solicitud = "Movistar";
              elseif($resultado['tipo_solicitud']==2)
                $solicitud = "Digitel";
              elseif($resultado['tipo_solicitud']==3)
                $solicitud = "Directv";
                elseif($resultado['tipo_solicitud']==4)
                $solicitud = "Movistar TV";
              else
                $solicitud = "ERROR";



              if($resultado['prioridad']==300)
                $prioridad = "<div class=\"tooltip\"><span class=\"white-text green\" style=\"padding:5px;border-radius:5px;\">300</span>";
              elseif($resultado['prioridad']==400)
                $prioridad = "<div class=\"tooltip\"><span class=\"white-text green\" style=\"padding:5px;border-radius:5px;\">400</span>";

                 elseif($resultado['prioridad']==500)
                $prioridad = "<div class=\"tooltip\"><span class=\"white-text green\" style=\"padding:5px;border-radius:5px;\">500</span>";

                 elseif($resultado['prioridad']==600)
                $prioridad = "<div class=\"tooltip\"><span class=\"white-text green\" style=\"padding:5px;border-radius:5px;\">600</span>";

                 elseif($resultado['prioridad']==700)
                $prioridad = "<div class=\"tooltip\"><span class=\"white-text green\" style=\"padding:5px;border-radius:5px;\">700</span>";

                 elseif($resultado['prioridad']==800)
                $prioridad = "<div class=\"tooltip\"><span class=\"white-text green\" style=\"padding:5px;border-radius:5px;\">800</span>";

                 elseif($resultado['prioridad']==900)
                $prioridad = "<div class=\"tooltip\"><span class=\"white-text green\" style=\"padding:5px;border-radius:5px;\">900</span>";

                 elseif($resultado['prioridad']==1000)
                $prioridad = "<div class=\"tooltip\"><span class=\"white-text green\" style=\"padding:5px;border-radius:5px;\">1000</span>";

                 elseif($resultado['prioridad']==1500)
                $prioridad = "<div class=\"tooltip\"><span class=\"white-text green\" style=\"padding:5px;border-radius:5px;\">1500</span>";

                 elseif($resultado['prioridad']==2000)
                $prioridad = "<div class=\"tooltip\"><span class=\"white-text green\" style=\"padding:5px;border-radius:5px;\">2000</span>";


              else
                $prioridad = "<div class=\"tooltip\"><span class=\"white-text red\" style=\"padding:5px;border-radius:5px;\">BAJA</span>";





              if($resultado['status']==1){

                $cierrep = "";
                $status = "<span class=\"white-text blue\" style=\"padding:5px;border-radius:5px;\">Por Revisar</span>";
              }
              elseif($resultado['status']==2){

                $cierrep = "";
                $status = "<span class=\"white-text yellow darken-3\" style=\"padding:5px;border-radius:5px;\">Revisado</span>";
              }
              elseif($resultado['status']==3){

                $cierrep = "";
                $status = "Cerrado";
              }
              elseif($resultado['status']==4){

                $cierrep = "";
                $status = "<span class=\"white-text brown\" style=\"padding:5px;border-radius:5px;\">Reabierto</span>";
              }
              elseif($resultado['status']==5){

                $status = "<span class=\"white-text brown\" style=\"padding:5px;border-radius:5px;\">Revisado</span>";
                $cierrep = "class=\"danger\"";
              }
              elseif($resultado['status']==6){

                $status = "<span class=\"white-text green\" style=\"padding:5px;border-radius:5px;\">Autorizado</span>";
                $cierrep = "";
              }
              elseif($resultado['status']==7){

                $status = "<span class=\"white-text red\" style=\"padding:5px;border-radius:5px;\">No autorizado</span>";
                $cierrep = "";
              }

              if(strlen($resultado['archivo'])>0)
                $archivo = "Si";
              else
                $archivo = "No";

              if($resultado_usuario['id_cede']==11)
                $cede = "Tu Primera Empresa";


                $fecha = array();

                if($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 2 || $_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 4){

                  $fecha = explode("-" ,$resultado['t_fcreacion']);

                  $hora = $resultado['t_hcreacion'];

                }
                else{

                  $fecha = explode("-" ,$resultado['fecha_creacion']);

                  $hora = $resultado['hora_creacion'];
                }
                $fecha[0] = $fecha[0]%1000;

                if($resultado['informe'])
                  $cerrado_sistema = "<i class=\"fa fa-bullhorn\"></i>";
                else
                  $cerrado_sistema = '';

              if($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 2 || $_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 4)
                    echo "<tr ".$cierrep.">
                      <td><a class=\"btn red especial hvr-pulse \" href=\"checkTicket-1-".$resultado['id_ticket']."\">".$resultado['id_ticket']."</a></td>
                      <td>".$solicitud."</td>
                      <td>".$prioridad."</td>
                      <td>".$resultado['titulo']."</td>

                      <td>".$status."</td>
                      <td>".$fecha[2]."/".$fecha[1]."/".$fecha[0]."</td>
                      <td>".$hora."</td>
                    </tr>";
                else
                    echo "<tr ".$cierrep.">
                      <td><a class=\"btn red especial hvr-pulse\" href=\"checkTicket-1-".$resultado['id']."\">".$resultado['id']."</a></td>
                      <td>".$solicitud."</td>
                      <td>".$prioridad."</td>
                      <td>".$resultado['titulo']."</td>

                      <td>".$status."</td>
                      <td>".$fecha[2]."/".$fecha[1]."/".$fecha[0]."</td>
                      <td>".$hora."</td>
                      <td>".$cerrado_sistema."</td>
                    </tr>";

                    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"registros\" id=\"registros\" value=\"".$registros."?>\">";

            }

            ?>
        </tbody>


      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

cuando trato de añadir el arhivo sin el php , el no me da problema pero me genera error a la hora de cargar todo el php.
Pretendo mostrar la tabla y que se actualice cada 5 segundos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que en tu archivo **"datos.php"** das por hecho la conexión y hace falta que incluyas el archivo que realiza dicho proceso.

Ejemplo:

> datos.php

```
    <!-- ... html code -->
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php

        require ("clases/baseDatos.class.php"); //Tu clase declarada
        $conexion = new baseDatos(); //Tu instancia debe saber de que clase proviene

        //resto del código...
      ?>
```

Ya que al ser una petición asíncrona no convive con el código **"index.php"** implementado en tu archivo y es necesario que incluyas tus archivos de conexión.

Espero esto solucione tu problema , saludos!

Comment: en efecto, ya lo habia solucionado , gracias frank. añadi las clases de la conexion y otras 2 y listo .